# State Space Search: A* and Breadth First Search

Tags: algorithm, search, breadth-first-search, a-star, state-space

So I have implemented 2 different solvers for the game Sokoban.

The solvers is simple, given a starting state(position), if initial state is the goal state then return result. Else generate child states and store them into whatever data structure correspond to the algorithm. (Queue for BFS and a priority queue for A*) It then pops the first child state from the data structure to check if it's goal state else generate child state and store into structure, repeats this process until a goal state is found.

At the moment, the A* algorithm is indeed better than the BFS so that less nodes was generated before it finds the result. However, my problem is that the A* algorithm takes longer to compute. For example in one of the levels, the BFS algorithm generated 26000 nodes whereas the A* only generated 3488, yet the A* took a second longer than the BFS to complete.

From using time profiler I have concluded that the Priority queue data structure that was used to store the nodes is responsible for this slow down. Because every time a node is inserted into the queue the priority queue has to run the heuristic function algorithm to determine if the new state should be the closest state to the goal state (So it places that node in the first thing in the queue).

Now my question is, do you guys think it's a problem with my implementation or this is normal due to the overhead caused in calculating the heuristic function.

Comment: If you're writing in Python, `PriorityQueue` is slow, use `heapq` instead (unless you're multithreading)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another hypothesis to look into (hypotheses is the best we can do without having your code available to look at): maybe you're re-computing your heuristic score (which I assume is a relatively expensive thing to compute in your case) unnecessarily often.

Where in your code do you compute the heuristic score? Do you

1. do this once for every node, right before pushing it into the priority queue, and then store the result inside some `Node` object such that you can instantly retrieve it when you need it?
2. Or do you only compute the heuristic score inside whatever `Comparator` function/functor/etc. is used by your Priority Queue to determine ordering of nodes?

In the second case, you'll very frequently re-compute the heuristic score for nodes for which you've already done so before. For example, suppose you have 100 nodes currently in the Priority Queue, and you try to insert a new node. In the second case, inserting that new node will likely require comparisons with a bunch out of those 100 existing nodes before you've figured out where the new one belongs, and may therefore require a bunch of additional heuristic score computations.

If you went with the first option (which is what I'd recommend), those 100 existing nodes and the new node to add will all already have their heuristic score computed (precisely once), and stored in memory as a member variable. Performing a bunch of comparisons with a bunch of existing nodes will be very cheap, it will only require fetching the already-computed heuristic scores and not require re-computing them.

Actually, based on the text in your question, I suspect you're indeed currently using the (inefficient) second implementation. Otherwise your Priority Queue wouldn't be calling the heuristic function at all.

---

If, with the more efficient first implementation described above, you're still struggling with an overly-costly heuristic function, you could try investigating if it's possible to write a more efficient incremental implementation during the generation of successor states. Whether or not this is possible depends very much on exactly what your heuristic function is doing. But, I can imagine that in some cases, if you already have

- Current state `s`
- Current heuristic score `h(s)`
- Move to successor state `s'`

you may be able to derive an efficient, incremental algorithm that computes, based on what move was made, how `h(s)` can be incrementally modified to determine `h(s')` (and then you can store it immediately in the node for `s'`)

Comment: Yes I am indeed using the second method you've mentioned, now that I've implemented the first method I see a drastic improvement in terms of running time! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're actually using a stack and not a queue for BFS? If you are using a stack, what you're doing is a DFS and that may not always give you the shortest path to the goal.

As for why your A* is slower, I think it is hard to say without knowing the complexity of your heuristic function, assuming your priority queue is doing O(Log(N)) inserts/removals (if it is not, there's your problem). If your heuristic is doing a lot of work it might dominate the computation needed and negate any gains from looking at fewer nodes.

A possible solution if the heuristic function is indeed the culprit is to use a simpler heuristic.

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem with your implementation. Heuristics are used when you want to solve your problem [faster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heuristic_(computer_science)) than with a basic (but probably exact) method. They trade optimality for speed: you risk getting a non-perfect solution in exchange for getting it quickly. It makes no sense to use a heuristic that makes your method slower than its exact version.

Of course, it's not possible to be more helpful without knowing a lot more about your implementation, but I can assure you that if your heuristic makes your solver slower, it's not worth it to use it.